# angular 2 window.open() callback

Tags: angular, window.open

I opened new window in angular 2 using window.open(MyURL,title,options).
I need a callback when this popup window is closed.
New in angular 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` event

```
let myWindow = window.open(MyURL, title, options);
myWindow.onbeforeunload = () => {
  //Do something
}
```